# Zooming on UIScrollView with paging enabled and multiple images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, zooming

I Have a `UIScrollview` with a `UIImageView` inside where I scroll from an image to another.

I used the [TapToZoom Apple sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008904) to implement the zoom but whenever I zoom the scrollview starts from the begining rather than the active image.

Here's a piece of my code :

Init and populate the imageview :

```
table = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:7];
for(int count = 1; count <= 7; count++)
{
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.jpg", count];
    UIImage  *image    = [UIImage imageNamed:fileName];
    [table addObject:image];
    if (image == nil) {
        break;
    }
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    imageView.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
```

Implement Tap Gesture :

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
```

The `handleDoubleTap` method zooms to the center of the the `imageView` and brings the scrollview to the begigining of the paging.

I searched a lot about this, but was unable to find a way to zoom on the actual displayed image.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Checkout the PhotoScroller sample from Apple:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Although this is potentially quite a good answer, it is essentially a **"link only"** answer. You should include some information from your links so that if the information behind the links is ever changed/lost, the answer still makes sense. See [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)